# yeoman generator for Angular restify Mongo project

Tags: yeoman

The stack I have been using for a while is Angular-restify-Mongo

I am wondering if there are any yeoman generator for them out there ?

If not .. what alternative generator can i use to quick start the project and then incorporate the missing elements ?

Answer (score 0):

For now I found just this - https://github.com/kmees/generator-restify-live . It's restify generator.